# Removing empty items from a list (Python)

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I'm reading a file in Python that isn't well formatted, values are separated by multiple spaces and some tabs too so the lists returned has a lot of empty items, how do I remove/avoid those?

This is my current code:

```
import re

f = open('myfile.txt','r') 

for line in f.readlines(): 
    if re.search(r'\bDeposit', line):
        print line.split(' ')

f.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in open("file"):
    if " Deposit" in line:
         line=line.rstrip()
         print line.split()
```

Update:

```
for line in open("file"):
    if "Deposit" in line:
         line=line.rstrip()
         print line[line.index("Deposit"):].split()
```

Comment: Note that `" Deposit" in line` is not equivalent to `re.search(r'\bDeposit', line)`. The latter will match `"this,Deposit"`, while the former won't.

Answer (score 11):

Don't explicitly specify `' '` as the delimiter. `line.split()` will split on all whitespace. It's equivalent to using `re.split`:

```
>>> line = '  a b   c \n\tg  '
>>> line.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g']
>>> import re
>>> re.split('\s+', line)
['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', '']
>>> re.split('\s+', line.strip())
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g']
```

Comment: forgot that string.split() with no argument split on _runs_ of whitespace. +1

Comment: Great, it did remove almost all whitespace from the lines, except one at the beginning and one at the end, strange.

Comment: re.split('\s+', line.strip()) will fix that

Comment: @jcoon: or `line.strip().split()`

Comment: Nimbuz, `line.split()` will take care of stripping whitespace at the start/end.

Answer (score 1):

```
linesAsLists = [line.split() for line in open('myfile.txt', 'r') if 'Deposit' in line)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do `line.strip()` before handling it? Also, you could use `re.split` to use a regex like '\s+' as your delimiter.

Comment: `for line in f.readlines(): line.strip(); continue_processing`...SO comments aren't friendly to Python code.

Comment: this will only remove whitespace from the head/tail of the string

Comment: If you do `line.split()` with no arguments, you get `strip` for free.  `' a b   c  d        '.split()  == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`